# Can I trigger a angular.js blur event on a website through a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a chrome extension which I'd like to automatically fill in some forms on a specific web application.
The web application uses angular.js and each input has a blur event which validates the values (ng-blur="validateValue(input)").

I can get the value in the inputs but for the web application to actually receive them the validateValue method has to be triggered.

Is there any way that I can trigger the ng-blur through my extension?

I've tried:
- calling the blur method (both native and jquery).
- calling focus before calling blur

Comment: In the content script inject a `<script>` element that will trigger the event: [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)

Comment: I'm trying to. Triggering the event however proves difficult =(

Comment: On the other hand, maybe simply *blur* it like `someInputElement.blur()`? Or focus another element or document.body?

Comment: @wOxxOm I've tried.. it doesn't trigger the event handlers that have been added to it by the web application :(

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

I also faced the same issue while developing chrome extension which scraps an angular website.
I have wasted many days in search for the solution.

Good news is that I found the solution that worked for me.

Create an event with **input** & followed by **blur** event. Dispatch these event in the same order. eg.

```
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
elem.dispatchEvent(new Event('blur'));
```

This will trigger **ng-blur="validateValue(input)"**.